# Snippets organising tool for windows

Tags: windows-7, code-snippets

Is there any similar tools like Snippets(http://www.snippetsapp.com/),Code Collector Pro(http://www.mcubedsw.com/software/codecollectorpro) for to organize code snippets in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try [Snippely](http://code.google.com/p/snippely/) ?

I believe that is less complete than Snippets but is an alternative for Windows.

Comment: Thanks , it is enough to store

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows 8, you might like Snipppet app, it's optimized for touchscreen devices. Check it out here: http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/snipppet/8d7ff457-58c8-4916-b3e6-1ac07daba0f4

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the app.

Answer (score 0):

We've released Windows for Snippets as part of our new project along with Snippets for Mac. Take a look at [snippets.me](http://snippets.me/).